# How to change boundingbox size in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a cocos2d game where I need to have a ball shaped sprite that is 140x140, but i want it's bounding box to be only 70x70 in size, so that only the center of the ball collides. If tried to edit the bounding box's size after the sprite is created, but it looks like the boundingbox property is not assignable. I've also tried to specify the rect in the constructor using `initWithFile:rect:` but then the sprite is cut and only the colliding part is drawn, and I want the whole sprite to be drawn, but just the center of it to be reacting to collisions. Is it possible to do this via boundingbox or is this property directly bound to the size of the drawn sprite?

Comment: make your own property ie collisionBox so you can have both variants in parallel

Comment: I'll do that, for some reason I thought the boundingBox variable was meant to represent the collision box and that the correct way to do what I want was to edit it, but I guess it just represents the drawn sprite's size. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary bounding box when you want to test for collision :

```
CGRect tempBoundingBox = CGRectInset(ball.boundingxBox, ball.boundingBox.width / 4, ball.boundingBox.height / 4);

if (CGRectContainsRect(tempBoundingBox, otherSprite.boundingBox) {
    // Do collision stuff here
}
```

The `CGRectInset` decreases your rectangle size by the given delta width and delta height while maintaining its center point the same as the original. (look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectInset) for more details).

In the above case it will create a bounding box of half the size of the original rectangle around the center point of the ball sprite